# How to install l2cs on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, pip

I have to install **[l2cs](https://github.com/kemitche/l2cs)** on my 12.04 ubuntu server but I don't know how to do that.

I'm beginner on dedicate servers and I need to some help to do that.
Can someone to provide a set-by-step tutorial how to install it ?

The instructions from github are

```
Run setup.py install to install the module
```

But I have no ideea how to do that ? Is need to upload the repository on my server, if yes, where ?

So a complete guideline about that is very welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you should post this on AskUbuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/kemitche/l2cs.git
cd l2cs
python setup.py install
```

Comment: "this library is not needed except for consumers who have yet to upgrade to the new API version" ... based on the usage of ubuntu 12.04, OP probably has yet to upgrade

Comment: indeed. fair point